# Cannot install face_recognition using pip install face_recognition on Win10

Tags: python, windows, opencv, face-recognition

I get the error

Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Running setup.py install for dlib did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [58 lines of output]
running install
running build
running build_py
package init file 'tools\python\dlib_*init*_.py' not found (or not a regular file)
running build_ext
Building extension for Python 3.10.4 (tags/v3.10.4:9d38120, Mar 23 2022, 23:13:41) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\amade\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_k5e982w\dlib_237006073dfd4b13993bf60b7ecb3629\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\amade\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_k5e982w\dlib_237006073dfd4b13993bf60b7ecb3629\build\lib.win-amd64-3.10 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\Users\amade\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\amade\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_k5e982w\dlib_237006073dfd4b13993bf60b7ecb3629\build\lib.win-amd64-3.10 -A x64'
-- Building for: Visual Studio 17 2022
-- Selecting Windows SDK version  to target Windows 10.0.19044.
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:14 (project):
No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.

```
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:14 (project):
    No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.



  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/amade/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-_k5e982w/dlib_237006073dfd4b13993bf60b7ecb3629/build/temp.win-amd64-3.10/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  See also "C:/Users/amade/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-_k5e982w/dlib_237006073dfd4b13993bf60b7ecb3629/build/temp.win-amd64-3.10/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
    File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\amade\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_k5e982w\dlib_237006073dfd4b13993bf60b7ecb3629\setup.py", line 222, in <module>
      setup(
    File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 153, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
      return orig.install.run(self)
    File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 568, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\amade\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_k5e982w\dlib_237006073dfd4b13993bf60b7ecb3629\setup.py", line 134, in run
      self.build_extension(ext)
    File "C:\Users\amade\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_k5e982w\dlib_237006073dfd4b13993bf60b7ecb3629\setup.py", line 171, in build_extension
      subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
    File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py", line 369, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\amade\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_k5e982w\\dlib_237006073dfd4b13993bf60b7ecb3629\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\amade\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_k5e982w\\dlib_237006073dfd4b13993bf60b7ecb3629\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.10', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\\Users\\amade\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\amade\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_k5e982w\\dlib_237006073dfd4b13993bf60b7ecb3629\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.10', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> dlib

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.

Comment: just in case the official documentation in requirements says that `Windows not officially supported, but might work` https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition I have tried to install the package on my windows 10 - Nope, it does not want to install

Comment: @GreyMurav Will we have to  use virtual environment to run linux  and try it there ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. I had to modify my Visual Studio install from Start menu programs, and include latest MSVC and include Windows 10 SDK under Individual Components

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps below to install `face_recognition` python package on `Windows 10`.

The instruction has been tested on `Windows 10 64bit, python 3.9.`

##### Step 1

Download CMake installation package for your OS from [official site](https://cmake.org/download/)

##### Step 2

Install downloaded CMake installation package. Please make sure that `Add CMake to system PATH` option has been selected during the installation.

##### Step 3

Reboot your OS (restart computer)

##### Step 4

Run `pip install dlib`
It tooks several minutes so be prepared to wait

##### Step 5

If it completes without any errors, you're all set. Run `pip install face_recognition` to install face_recognition.

**Result**

[image]